# How to publish dnn website?

Tags: asp.net, web, module, dotnetnuke, publish

I have a site in DNN 6.2.1, and I create a simple module in this site. i install my module controls from  Host\Extension\Add New Control, and it works by source code well.
Now I want to have a package from my module without source code, to install it in other sites. 
when I use create package from my module properties in extension page, it creates a package with all my source code.
When I publish my site in order to publish my module source and give me a DLL, visual studio gives me lots of errors from other controls, most of them tell this :

**"Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetNuke, Version=6.2.1.253, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."**

What can I do to have a install package from my module without source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend you go through the DNNTaskManager tutorial for doing module development, you will find it is much easier to develop modules using a template that creates "packages" for INSTALL and SOURCE.

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/Page/Module-Development

You can find the templates at

https://christoctemplate.codeplex.com/

For DNN 6, you will want to grab an older version of the template, likely v1.1 or older

Comment: i used u'r template and all documentions about how to use it, and it works well. tanks a lot.